# Функция клонирования таблицы

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер! С наступающим новым годом, Вас друзья! У меня возник вопрос, почему не опознается insertRow и insertCell в данной функции? Суть задачи такова в html-документе есть таблица какая-то, и ее надо клонировать. Пишу на чистом JavaScript, без всяких фреймворков... Вот код, подскажите как решить проблему (привожу кусок класса - функцию которая клонирует таблицу вместе с ее данными):

```
 // функция клонирования таблицы
     this.copyTable = function (ParentTable,ChildrenTable) 
     {
        // подключаем родительскую таблицу из которой будут браться данные...
        var parenttable = document.getElementsByClassName(ParentTable)[0]; 
        // создаем дочернюю таблицу в которую будут импортированны данные....
        var mytable2 = document.createElement(ChildrenTable);

        // последовательнный перебор всех рядов в родительской таблице
        for (var r=0; r<parenttable.rows.length; r++) 
        {
           var newRow = mytable2.insertRow(r);
           // последовательный перебор всех ячеек 
           for (var c=0; c<parenttable.rows[r].cells.length; c++) 
           {
              // значение ячейки в родительской таблице
              var parent_cls = parenttable.rows[r].cells[c];
              // создаем ячейку в дочерней таблице
              var newCell = newRow.insertCell(c);
              // присваиваем значение их родительской таблицы в дочернюю...
              newCell.innerHTML = parent_cls; 
              newCell.className = ChildrenTable;

           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: а кто такой this в этой программе ?

Comment: вообще с виду идея неправильная. почему бы не сделать аргументом уже таблицу а не её класс и почему бы не присвоить новой таблице innerHTML старой ? или не воспользоваться cloneNode ? кроме того наименования  Parent и Children очень плохо отражают отношения между этими таблицами.

Comment: This - это так обращение к методу объекта идет. В разметке Html-кода просто указан только класс таблицы, name и id отсутствуют, потому аргумент класс таблицы... Не знаю правильно ли понял вас или нет... А насчет innerHTML, что можно без перебора всех ячеек просто присвоить содержимое таблицы? Как это @eicto будет выглядеть скиньте пару строчек кода исходя из моего примера... И насчет insertCell и insertRow все равно проблема, в дальнейшем надо добавлять новые столбцы и строки в таблицу по команде пользователя. Почему они не работают? В консоли ругается на неизвестный метод...

Comment: вот пример, ваша функция - одна строчка. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bQSFB/

Comment: Спасибо за пример! Сделайте его как ответ и я его отмечу как верный. Я javascript только начал изучать просто... потому и спрашиваю что да как. Хотя клонирование наверное не подойдет, так как у меня идет копирование данных, но класс таблицы и ячеек будет отличаться от родительского, а это значит каждой ячейке надо поменять класс, а в дальнейшем и содержимое. В примере я правда не увидел как не целиком строки добавлять или изменять, а к конкретным ячейкам обращаться. insertRow и insertCell не работают что ли? Устаревшие или что?

Comment: нет, они должны работать, просто не вижу в них смысла особого.

Comment: Ну просто как же мне тогда обращаться к конкретным ячейкам, чтобы присваивать им новые классы и содержимое? В чем тогда смысл их?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял задачу, но зачем такие сложности? Почему нельзя было использовать `el.cloneNode(true)`, а для переноса ячеек `el.insertBefore`?

Можно сделать что-то типа этого: http://jsfiddle.net/ufxx3/1/

Comment: Хороший код, понравился! Прямо высший пилотаж)). Только одна поправка, что нельзя в задаче именовать таблицу через id или name. Вся таблица и ее ячейки должны иметь только class="t1". А для клонов class="t2". А так все окей!

Comment: Это для примера, `table1` легко заменяется на `el.getElementsByClassName('t1')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

В принципе решил свою ошибку. Если кому интересно можете поизучать. Сделал функцию копирования таблицы с изменением классов у всех тегов таблицы и функцию клонирования, как подсказал коллега [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto). Ошибка была что я на строке

> var childrentable =
> document.createElement(******);

присваивал класс таблицы, а не тип тега table, потому insertRow и insertCell не срабатывали.

```
 // функция копирования данных таблицы с изменением названий класса ячеек и всей таблицы
     this.copyTable = function (ParentTable,ChildrenTable) 
     {
        // подключаем родительскую таблицу из которой будут браться данные...
        var parenttable = document.getElementsByClassName(ParentTable)[0]; 
        // создаем дочернюю таблицу в которую будут импортированны данные....
        var childrentable = document.createElement("table");
        childrentable.className = ChildrenTable;

        // последовательнный перебор всех рядов в родительской таблице
        for (var r=0; r < parenttable.rows.length; r++) 
        {
           var newRow = childrentable.insertRow(r); 
           // последовательный перебор всех ячеек 
           for (var c=0; c < parenttable.rows[r].cells.length; c++) 
           {
              // значение ячейки в родительской таблице
              var parent_cls = parenttable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
              // создаем ячейку в дочерней таблице
              var newCell = newRow.insertCell(c);
              // присваиваем значение их родительской таблицы в дочернюю...
              // и имя класса свое собственное...
              newCell.innerHTML = parent_cls; 
              newCell.className = ChildrenTable;

           }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(childrentable);
     }

     // функция полного клонирования элемента страницы (в том числе и таблиц)
     // (параметр используется только class эдемента, а не id или name).
     this.cloneElement = function(ParentElement)
     {
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(ParentElement)[0];
        document.body.appendChild(elem.cloneNode(true));
     }   
  }
```

И вот в готовом варианте что я хотел получить http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2bg/1/